# Correcting mis-configured celery (running with supervisord)

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, supervisord, celeryd

I started running celery for tasks in a Python/Django web project, hosted on a single VM with 8 cores or CPUs. I need to improve the configuration now - I've made rookie mistakes.

I use `supervisor` to handle celery workers and beat. In `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`, I have two worker-related conf files - `celery1.conf` and `celery1.conf`. Should I...

1) **Remove one of them?** Both spawn different workers. I.e. the former conf file has `command=python manage.py celery worker -l info -n celeryworker1`. The latter has `command=python manage.py celery worker -l info -n celeryworker2`. And it's authoritatively [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046332/4936905) to run 1 worker per machine.

2) **Tinker with `numprocs` in the conf?** Currently in `celery1.conf`, I've defined `numprocs=2`. In `celery2.conf`, I've defined `numprocs=3`* (see footer later). At the same time, in `/etc/default/celeryd`, I have `CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"`. So what's going on? supervisor's `numprocs` takes precedence over `concurrency` in celeryd, or what? Should I set `numprocs=0`?

---

*total numprocs over both files = 2+3 = 5. This checks out. `sudo supervisorctl` shows 5 celery worker processes. But in newrelic, I see **45 processes running** for celeryd. What the heck?! Even if each proc created by supervisor is actually giving birth to 8 procs (via celeryd), total `numprocs x concurrency = 5 x 8 = 40`. That's 5 less than the 45 shown by newrelic. Need guidance in righting these wrongs.

Compare screenshots:

[image: 5 celery workers as per supervisorctl]

vs

[image: 45 running celery processes as per newrelic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it's authoritatively stated here to run 1 worker per machine

Actually, it's *advised* ("I would suggest") to only run one worker per machine *for this given use case*.

You may have pretty good reason to do otherwise (for example having different workers for different queues...), and the celery doc states that how many worker / how many processes per worker (concurrency) works best really depends on you tasks, usage, machine and whatnots.

wrt/ `numprocs` in supervisor conf and `concurrency` in celery, these are totally unrelated (well, almost...) things. A celery "worker" is actually one main process spawning `concurrency` children (which are the ones effectively handling your tasks). Supervisor's `numprocs` tells supervisor how many processes (here: the celery workers) it should launch. So if you have one celery conf with `numprocs` = 2 and another one with `numproc` = 3,  this means you launch a total of 5 *parents* worker processes - each of them spawning `n` subchilds, where - by default - `n` is your server's cpus count. This means you have a total of 5 + (5*8) = 45 worker subprocesses running.

Wether you actually need that many workers is a question only you can answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation (and hat!). I guess this brings me to investigating how to reliably tune the number of workers I need. Any direction you can point me into?

Comment: Well... First think of what kind of resources your tasks compete for vs how many of that resource is available (given other processes running on the same server), how long your tasks run, how often they are called etc - globally what are your usage patterns. If you have tasks with very different needs / usage patterns, you may want to dispatch them to different queues / different servers (possibly with different resource allocations depending on the queues a server will handle).