# How to lock variable in celery task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, locking, celery

I have a celery task, that mangles some variable. It works perfect if I set a single celery worker, but when I use concurrency, it all messed up. How could I lock the critical section, where variable is mangled?

inb4: using Python 3.6, Redis both as broker and result backed. threading.Lock doesn't help in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as celery runs on multiple workers (processes) thread lock would not help, because it works inside **single** process. Moreover threading lock have use when you control overall process, while using celery there is no way to achieve that.

It means that celery requires distributed lock. For django I always use django-cache, as in: [here](https://russellneufeld.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/using-memcached-as-a-distributed-lock-from-within-django/). If you need more generic locks especially Redis based, working for any python app you can use [sherlock](https://github.com/vaidik/sherlock).

Comment: Stumbled upon first url you pointed out while was googling, but for some reason was thinking there are easier ways. Anyway, sherlock solved the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a question with 2+ years, but right now I'm tuning my celery configs and I came to this topic.

I am using python 2.7 with Django 1.11 and celery 4 in a linux machine. I am using rabbitmq as a broker.

My configs implies to have celery running as daemon and celery beat to handle scheduled tasks.

And so, with a dedicated queue for a given task, you may configure this queue with a worker (process) with concurrency=1 (subprocesses).

This solution solves concurrency problems for celery to run a task, but in your code, if you run the task without celery, it won't respect concurrency principles.

Example code:

```
CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
   Queue('celery_periodic', default_exchange, routing_key='celery_periodic'),
   Queue('celery_task_1', celery_task_1_exchange, routing_key='celery_task_1'),
)

default_exchange            = Exchange('celery_periodic', type='direct')
celery_task_1_exchange      = Exchange('celery_task_1', type='direct')

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
   'celery-task-1': {
       'task':     'tasks.celery_task_1',
       'schedule': timedelta(minutes=15),
       'queue':    'celery_task_1'
   },
}
```

and finally, in /etc/default/celeryd (docs here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#example-configuration):

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2"
CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1 --time-limit=600 -Q:worker1 celery_periodic -Q:worker2 celery_task_1"
```

> --concurrency N means you will have exactly N worker subprocesses for your worker instance (meaning the worker instance can handle N conccurent tasks) (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903753/9412892).

Read more here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency

BR,
Eduardo